# $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges $\Rightarrow \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mathrm{Log}(1+a_{n})$ converges, $a_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $a_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ ; is it true that convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_{n}$  implies convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\mathrm{Log}(1+a_{n})$ ? Why ?

Here $\mathrm{Log}$ is the the principal branch of the logarithm.

Comment: If $a_n > 0 $, then it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true. Consider

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Then you have

$$\log (1+a_n) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{1}{2(n+1)} + O\left((n+1)^{-3/2}\right),$$

so $\sum \log (1+a_n)$ is a combination of a (conditionally) convergent alternating series, a divergent harmonic series, and an absolutely convergent series, altogether divergent.

The *absolute* convergence of $\sum a_n$ entails the *absolute* convergence of $\sum \log (1+a_n)$, and vice versa, however, since

$$\frac{2}{3} \lvert u\rvert \leqslant \lvert \log (1+u)\rvert \leqslant \frac{4}{3}\lvert u\rvert$$

for $\lvert u\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ (with the principal branch of the logarithm).

Comment: but in the real case, can't we say that if $a_{n} \rightarrow 0 $ then $a_{n}$ is asymptotic to $log(1+ a_{n})$ and so the $2$ series have the same behaviour ?

Comment: it might be worth explaining why $\sum\log(1+a_n)$ doesn't converge here (group adjacent terms and then look again).  WLOG: two _sequences_ being asymptotic implies equivalent properties, but that doesn't necessarily hold with series.